# System.Threading.ThreadPool excluding a core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, multicore

I have a multi-core architecture computer that is executing processes using .Net 4.5.2 System.Threading.ThreadPool namespace. The processes are long duration math computations. These processes might execute for days and even weeks. I do not want to create my own Thread Pools. Using the System.Threading.ThreadPool namespace is very nice. However, on my multi-core architecture computer, the Thread Pool Manager is very greedy and load balances across all of the cores. Unfortunately, my processes on each core are also greedy. They want to monopolize the core and execute at 100% until it completes its assignment. I'm fine with this, except that the operating system freezes up. Literally, I can't move the mouse around and interact with the desktop. What I would like to do is reserve one of the Cores for the Operating System, so that the mouse and gui are still responsive. It seems logical to exclude a core (and its available threads) for the OS to operate.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using System.Threading.ThreadPool?

****ANSWER****

To begin, my question is faulty. This was due to my inexperience with the subject. Second, if your google search brought you to this question, it means that your thinking is also faulty; evidenced by your google search words. But this is good. Now you can learn the proper way. [And here it is.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362996/Multi-core-programming-using-Task-Parallel-Library)

The short answer to this question: System.Threading.ThreadPool cannot solve your issue.

A slightly better answer: The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is a set of public types and APIs in the System.Threading and System.Threading.Tasks namespaces in the .NET Framework 4.0. The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to efficiently use all the cores that are available. By using TPL, you can maximize the performance of your code while focusing on the work that your program is designed to accomplish.

Good luck and happy coding to you!

Comment: Why not just create `Environment.ProcessorCount - 1` threads in the threadpool?

Comment: May I ask _why_ your intent is to use ThreadPool? ThreadPool usually isn't for long-running operations but for relatively short tasks (where thread reusing saves resources and overhead). That said you may leave framework to do its job with threading and just **low down thread priority** (for each invocation).

Comment: I suppose throttling might be an alternative, but again not sure how to accomplish that with the System.Threading.ThreadPool namespace. Oh boy here come the down votes. Nice people around here!

Comment: Using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can set the `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to limit the number of cores used. For example I can set it for 7 on an 8 core machine and it will keep the equivalent of 1 core free for any other things.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I clearly indicate that I am executing long running math processes. If I DO NOT use the thread pool, with my experience level with computer programming, it forces me to create a separate executable for the math operation (picture having 8 console windows open) - and it still runs the core at 100%.

Comment: @Nathan: that sounds nice, in theory, but if a thread gets blocked I will want to have another thread start up and do work until the blocked thread is ready to proceed. Otherwise the entire core lies dormant until the blocked thread is resolved.

Comment: @Vlad: That looks very promising, I'll try it out now.

Comment: @sapbucket no, you do not need to setup different executables...just different threads...

Comment: @sapbucket That doesn't make any sense, you said these were computationally expensive operations. If they're getting blocked by I/O, that's not really true.

Comment: @sapbucket per your "but if a thread gets blocked I will want to have another thread start up and do work until the blocked thread is ready to proceed" remark, it really depends on HOW it will get blocked if this is even feasible to do. If they are being blocked by synchronous waits (like `Thread.Sleep`) I don't think you can accomplish what you want without a lot of difficulty. How do you expect these operations to get blocked?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: because the math operation relies on extracting a value from an external network resource. That resource may be blocked for reasons I can't control (perhaps another user is accessing it, blocking until they release it).

Answer (score 0):

> @ScottChamberlain: because the math operation relies on extracting a value from an external network resource. That resource may be blocked for reasons I can't control (perhaps another user is accessing it, blocking until they release it). –  sapbucket

What you need to do is separate the getting data from the network resource from the processing of that resoruce. Use a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) as a buffer to pipeline between your two parts.

```
BlockingCollection<YourData> _collection = new BlockingCollection<YourData>();

public void ProcessInParallel()
{
    //This starts up your workers, it will create the number of cores you have - 1 workers.
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for(int i = 0; i < Environment.NumberOfLogicalCores - 1; i++)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DataProcessorLoop, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    //This function could be done in parallel too, _collection.Add is fine with multiple threads calling it.
    foreach(YourData data in GetYourDataFromTheNetwork())
    {
        //Put data in to the collection, the first worker available will take it.
        _collection.Add(data);
    }

    //Let the consumers know you will not be adding any more data.
    _collection.CompleteAdding();

    //Wait for all of the worker tasks to drain the collection and finish.
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

private void DataProcessorLoop()
{
    //this will pull data from the collection of work to do, when there is no work to do
    //it will block until more work shows up or CompleteAdding is called.
    foreach(YourData data in _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        CrunchData(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. I will attempt this now. Thank you Scott